# Java Polymorphic Sorting Program changing order

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, polymorphism

I have to modify the insertionSort algorithm so that it sorts in descending order rather than ascending order. It should sort an array (of any size) from largest to smallest numbers rather then from smallest to the largest. Any suggessions please.

```
public class Sorting
{
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Sorts the specified array of objects using the selection
   //  sort algorithm.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public static void selectionSort (Comparable[] list)
   {
      int min;
      Comparable temp;

      for (int index = 0; index < list.length-1; index++)
      {
         min = index;
         for (int scan = index+1; scan < list.length; scan++)
            if (list[scan].compareTo(list[min]) < 0)
               min = scan;

         // Swap the values
         temp = list[min];
         list[min] = list[index];
         list[index] = temp;
      }
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Sorts the specified array of objects using the insertion
   //  sort algorithm.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public static void insertionSort (Comparable[] list)
   {
      for (int index = 1; index < list.length; index++)
      {
         Comparable key = list[index];
         int position = index;

         //  Shift larger values to the right
         while (position > 0 && key.compareTo(list[position-1]) < 0)
         {
            list[position] = list[position-1];
            position--;
         }

         list[position] = key;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I wonder what `Compare` does and how that might be used to effect the outcome of the algorithm...

Comment: In selection sort if(min!=index) then swap otherwise no need to swap.... just saying ....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)